# Selenium can't locate previously created IWebElement after navigating to the page for a second time

Tags: c#, .net, selenium

I have a sample test with a login page where I want to simulate a successful login, then logout and finally unsuccessful login with wrong password. When I navigate to the login page for the first time I use the following code to find the element:

`IWebElement username = wait.Until((x) => { return x.FindElement(By.Id("input-1")); });`

Then later after clearing cookies I navigate back to the same login page and I try to use the same element:

```
//navigating to the login page
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(panel);

//Verifying that the page is the one i am looking for
IWebElement signUp = wait.Until((x) => { return x.FindElement(By.Id("go_sign_up")); } );
Assert.IsNotNull(signUp);
//Try to add some info to username field
username.SendKeys("blabla");
```

The same element with the same id is present in the page but I get the following error in my test: 
`Message: OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException : stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

Sorry if the information is not enough, its my first time asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the page **DOM gets refreshed** when you leave the page and return.

Quickest way to solve will be to locate the element again once you return to the page.

I also suggest you read about the Page Object Model and using CacheLookup

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the code which cause stale element reference into this LOC :

```
 int attempts = 0;
    while(attempts < 2) {
        try {
            IWebElement username = wait.Until((x) => { return x.FindElement(By.Id("input-1")); });
            result = true;
            break;
        } catch(StaleElementException e) {
        }
        attempts++;
    }
```